# Log of Laravel Scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Where do the **Laravel stores the log of the scheduler** i.e if we set a scheduler at an interval of 2 hours and it has been executed at 12 pm then it should be executed at 2 pm?

How does Laravel know that the scheduler should not be executed at 1 pm?

Comment: I think you should read a bit more about cronjobs and how they work.

Answer (score 17):

I came across 2 ways to store logs.

1) Sending Output to a File. Check out [Laravel 5.8 Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#task-output)

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->everyMinute()
             ->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/inspire.log'));
}
```

2) Use cron monitoring [cronhub](https://cronhub.io/). You can check out the documentations here. 
[How to create and monitor scheduled tasks in Laravel applications](https://medium.com/@tik/how-to-create-and-monitor-scheduled-tasks-in-laravel-applications-784d4f7f8084)

Sorry I couldn't contribute more since I personally haven't used it. Hope this info helps. Cheers!

Comment: do we just var_dump something to send output to a file?