# Laravel Logger not Working inside console commands

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

I am using Laravel Logger(`Log::info()` to be specific) inside a Console Command and it is not working when it is scheduled (scheduled for two times a day), if i run the command manually as `php artisan command-name` it is working.

I have already tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan optimize`

My app.php :

```
'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),
'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
```

My .env :

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

My ide_helper :

```
'Log' => array(
            'debug'     => 'Monolog\Logger::addDebug',
            'info'      => 'Monolog\Logger::addInfo',
            'notice'    => 'Monolog\Logger::addNotice',
            'warning'   => 'Monolog\Logger::addWarning',
            'error'     => 'Monolog\Logger::addError',
            'critical'  => 'Monolog\Logger::addCritical',
            'alert'     => 'Monolog\Logger::addAlert',
            'emergency' => 'Monolog\Logger::addEmergency',
        )
```

Comment: [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627329/log-of-laravel-scheduler)
hope this help you